# Particle System location

Tags: unity

I have created a particle system.
In this particle system, I'm using a cylinder as a mesh.

It looks as I want it to, but its location is really strange:

[image]

In this screenshot one can see that in the Scene View window, there's a wide gap between the cylinder and the edge of the platform, and in the Game View window, there's no gap at all.

When I look at it from the Top View, it looks completely strange: It looks as if the cylinder was laying on the floor.

What is going on here, and how could I reliably place the particle system / the cylinder in my game at a certain location?

Thank you.

Edit: 
This is my setup:

[image]

Edit: I have recorded a video here to show the Gizmos:
[Unity Window](https://youtu.be/d_qVlCiNjA0)

Comment: You should include details here about how you configured your particle system, and how you authored the cylinder mesh.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the Inspector. What might be missing about the mesh? It's a cylinder which I have unwrapped in Blender and imported as an obj. Then I dragged the mesh into the "Mesh" slot of the Renderer.

Comment: For one, we don't know where its vertices are relative to its origin / the particle system's transform position. We can't see the transform gizmo in any of these screenshots.

Comment: I have recorded a video. Does this video reveal the required information?

Comment: Yep! Looks like you're using the wrong Render Alignment. I don't have time to write an answer just now, but I can tackle it later if you still need help when I get back.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the cause of the problem indeed. I have change the render alignment to "World", and now it works as I expected it. Thank you!!

Comment: ps: Where have you been? :-) @"when I get back"

Comment: Glad it helped! Please add your solution as an Answer then. As for where I am, you can ask that in [chat] next time I'm online or [catch me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory). Comments aren't for chit-chatting. ;)